# CSS hover makes other elements move

Tags: css

I want to grow borders on hover. However it does impact all other elements positioning.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/s2m3vtbb/):**

```css
.nicePeopleItem  {
  display:inline-block;
}
.nicePeopleItem img{
  border-radius:48px;
  border: 4px solid #D568A8;
  padding: 2px; 
  transition-duration:0.3s; 
  cursor:pointer;
}
.nicePeopleItem img:hover{
  border: 10px solid #D568A8;
  transition-duration:0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="carrousel">
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>  
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>  
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>  
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add some margins, padding, some absolute positioning without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could replace the `border` with a `box-shadow`, e.g.

```
border: 10px solid #D568A8;
```

should become

```
box-shadow:  0 0 0 10px #D568A8;
```

By increasing only this property the computed width/height of the element won't change (because there's no *geometry* change) so this won't affect the position of the adjacent static images that will be partially overlapped by the `box-shadow`.

> [Codepen Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s2m3vtbb/3/)

Note: in case you didn't want the overlap at the `hover` state, just increase the margin between elements.

Comment: I can see a very thin white circle between border and shadow on hover. We could also change border to box-shadow on normal state to remove that.

Comment: You can ofcourse add extra margin at the start itself to compensate for the box-shadow's width. This will avoid the overlap :)

Comment: of course, but to me it's not clear if an overlap is wanted or not since the original question was about how to change the border width without changing the position of the other elements. I'll do an edit about it

Comment: Fair enough. I will leave that comment there just in-case OP doesn't want the overlap but would be ok to add extra margin :)

Answer (score 4):

That is because the elements have `display: inline-block`. This means that all the elements will be aligned to the baseline by default and so as one element becomes larger (due to the thicker border), it will push the other elements downwards.

You could add `vertical-align: top;` to the elements to make them all aligned to the top instead of the baseline and this would prevent the others from being pushed down. Note that, the elements after the one that is being hovered on would still be pushed to the right because of an increase in border of the one that is being hovered on. (*If you want to avoid this also from happening then using shadows instead of border like mentioned in [fcalderan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36080511/2606013) would be better.*)

```css
.nicePeopleItem {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nicePeopleItem img {
  border-radius: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #D568A8;
  padding: 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nicePeopleItem img:hover {
  border: 10px solid #D568A8;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="carrousel">
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>
  <div class="nicePeopleItem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What could we do to avoid it? When they have space in between elements but vertically.

Answer (score 4):

You can add negative margin to the hover to compensate the border-width growth.

Just add: margin:-6px;

```
.nicePeopleItem img:hover
{
  border: 10px solid #D568A8;
  transition-duration:0.3s;
  margin:-6px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qzwx7ow/)

It doesn't play very well with the transition though. Without transition this works perfectly.

Comment: this make the element shake !